# its given undefined. cant retrieve name from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, undefined

i want to get user data from firebase after login. when I get the name from database it is providing value as undefined.. why?

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if(user != null ){

  var email_id = user.email;
  var uid = user.uid;
  var name = user.userName; 
  var user = user;

  document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + email_id;
  document.getElementById("user_para1").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + uid;
  document.getElementById("user_para2").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + name;


}
```

Comment: please if one of u hv any idea please help me. this for my final year project and i am totally stucked here..

Comment: have you tried a debugger?

Comment: I would imagine firebase.auth is async, and you're not awaiting it, so user will always be null.

Comment: nooooo.. can u please tell me how?

Comment: but email and uid both are showing. But cant get the other details mr.@james

Comment: how to use debugger mr.@Soutzikevich..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that firebase auth saves only the following data:

```
email: 'user@example.com',
emailVerified: false,
phoneNumber: '+11234567890',
password: 'secretPassword',
displayName: 'John Doe',
photoURL: 'http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
disabled: false
```

So user.userName doesn't exist.

You can use **displayName** to save the username but if you really use it to save the name you can create a node called users in firebase realtime database where you could save the username based on UID, something like this:

```
users
   ->akdjf231dkeimdla
         ->username: jamesbond007
```

After you code could be:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if(user != null ){

 var email_id = user.email;
 var uid = user.uid;
 var name = user.displayName;

 document.getElementById("user_para").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + email_id;
 document.getElementById("user_para1").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + uid;
 document.getElementById("user_para2").innerHTML = "Welcome User : " + name;

 firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   //Here are reading the username from the database
   var username = snapshot.val().username;

 });

}
```

If you use firebase realtime database remember to add the firebase realtime database library.

For more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: @Jay, Sorry I didnt know it. Thank you for letting me know it.. Anyway u ar expert at Firebase.. can u do me a favor. Do u hv a php code for to retrieve user details after logged in.. according to the user Id.

Comment: @YasithSFonseka The Firebase Getting Started guide has PHP examples of how to read data from a collection or document. I don't know which details you want to retrieve but take a look at the guide [Reading Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#php)

Comment: @Jay okey i will try..Thank you :-)